# How do I resize a SF Symbol button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I'm trying to resize a SF Symbol button in SwiftUI. I've tried `.font(.system(size: 60))` and `.imageScale(.medium)` but it doesn't work. It still has this same error. This is my code:

```
var buttons: [Button<Image>] = [
    Button(action: {
        print("Add tapped")
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
    }
]
```

[image: Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to closure result type 'Image']

Comment: Why do you need an array for this and/or can't you apply the size when you use the buttons in your view?

Answer (score 4):

Take the help of `UIImage`.

```
var buttons: [Button<Image>] = [
    Button(action: {
        print("Add tapped")
    }) {
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 60))
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle.fill", withConfiguration: config) ?? UIImage()
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    }
]
```

But the question is still why you need this `[Button<Image>]` ???

Comment: thank you. It works! I'm new to this, I'm trying to make a customNavigationView.

Comment: @Na'imRoslan you can accept / upvote answere if it helped you

Comment: I’m sorry I can’t. I need 15 reputation to upvote. I’m sorry 

Answer (score 1):

If all fails there is an option to resize `UIImage`'s with `SFSymbols`. If you don't mind making the program a bit longer, I would recommend using,

```
extension UIImage {
    func resized(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

which resizes the UIImage. So you can initialize your `Image` with a  resized `UIImage`. The code will look something like...

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")!.resized(to: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)))
```